# Message of the day (MOTD) not working in vagrant with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ssh, ansible, vagrant, ubuntu-18.04

I can't get the message of the day to be displayed in my vagrant box and I wonder why.
I [created a gist for a reproducible example here](https://gist.github.com/trolologuy/59a81c915d50c590885093cd8debbf84) (it contains the `Vagrantfile` and the `playbook.yml` files).

Here's my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.require_version ">= 2.2.3"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 2048
    v.cpus = 2
  end  
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
  config.vm.hostname = "cli-tools"
  config.vm.provision "ansible", type: "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
  end

  config.ssh.extra_args = ["-t", "zsh; cd /home/vagrant"]
  config.ssh.forward_x11 = true
end
```

I provision my box with ansible, there I also create the `/etc/update-motd.d/01-custom` file.
The first line is `#!/bin/sh`.
The last line is `exit 0`.

Running `sudo run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/ > /dev/null` displays nothing (as expected).

Permissions are set as for the other scripts:

```
vagrant:~/ $ ls -la /etc/update-motd.d/                                                                                                                                                                                                             
total 64
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 20 09:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 97 root root 4096 Aug 20 08:16 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1220 Apr  9  2018 00-header
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 2387 Aug 20 09:14 01-custom
```

My `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` contains the following settings:

```
...
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd yes
...
```

Pam configuration in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
...
# Print the message of the day upon successful login.
# This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
# and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
...
```

Here's the `playbook.yml`

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Update apt cache
      apt:
        update_cache: yes
      become: yes

    - name: Install zsh
      apt:
        name: zsh
        state: present
      become: yes

    - name: Check current shell
      shell: if echo $0 = "zsh" ; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi
      register: zsh

    - name: Change default shell to zsh
      shell: 'sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh vagrant'
      when: zsh.stdout == "false"

    - name: Check if Oh My Zsh is already installed
      shell: '[ -d "/home/vagrant/.oh-my-zsh" ] && echo "true" || echo "false"'
      register: ohmyzsh_present

    - name: Install Oh My Zsh (it can take several minutes to complete)
      shell: 'sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)" "" --unattended'
      when: ohmyzsh_present.stdout == "false"

    - name: Check that the message of the day (motd) file.conf exists
      stat:
        path: /etc/update-motd.d/01-custom
      register: motd_custom

    - name: Create the message of the day (motd) file, if it doesnt exist already (/etc/update-motd.d/01-custom)
      file:
        path: /etc/update-motd.d/01-custom
        state: touch
        mode: 0755
        owner: root
        group: root
      become: yes
      become_user: root
      when: not motd_custom.stat.exists

    - name: Set message of the day (motd)
      blockinfile:
        path: /etc/update-motd.d/01-custom
        marker: ''
        block: |
          #!/bin/sh
          # System Overview
          echo "\033[33;1m\nSystem Overview\n\033[0m"
          /usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo

          # System Updates
          echo "\033[33;1m\nSystem Updates\n\033[0m"
          /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable
          exit 0
      become: yes
      become_user: root
      when: not motd_custom.stat.exists

    - name: Remove blank lines blockinfile put in
      lineinfile :
        path: /etc/update-motd.d/01-custom
        state: absent
        regexp: '^$'
      become: yes
      become_user: root

    - name: update ssh config file to add the motd
      shell: 'sed -i "s/.*PrintMotd.*/PrintMotd yes/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config && sudo service ssh restart'
      become: yes
      become_user: root
      when: not motd_custom.stat.exists
```

I use oh-my-zsh from within my box, could that be the issue there?
Globally speaking, I never got any "motd" displayed in vagrant.
What am I missing here?

Comment: this question (and answers) not solved my issue but helped me further https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207493/unit-systemd-resolved-service-is-masked

Answer (score 1):

You should run `service motd-news restart` or use the Ansible service module to restart `motd-news` after you add your motd file (or make any changes there).

FWIW You can also use the Ansible User module to set your user's shell to zsh instead of having to check what the current shell is. This will allow you to remove the shell check task.